# Grinding noise on transmision on a Ford Focus 1.4 i Zetec - 2002

Tags: ford, transmission, focus

Can anyone help me to find out where this grinding metallic noise comes from? Transmision fault? Bearing gone? or what?

Here is how it sounds - http://youtu.be/YGAeINSTtrQ . The first part is when the engine is in charge with the hand brake on and the second part is on the move with that noise coming constantly only when in 3rd gear at about 2200-2300 RPM, can hear the noise in 2nd 4th and 5th gear only when trying to drive with constant speed and in a gear too high for the actual speed.

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 2):

Do the test against the curb again with the hood up and look at the belt tensioner. My 2003 Zetec has been through four tensioners so far, and when they go they rattle hard when the engine is under load. If that's what's wrong with yours, you'll be able to see it shake violently in time to the rattling.

Answer (score 0):

The noise on your vehicle is the engine 'pinking'. You are overloading the engine when you produce the noise when stationary like in the clip. But, if you also have this noise when driving then the areas you need to check are: Engine Knock Sensor failure, engine coolant level/overheating. A system scan would show up any other possibilities such as an oxygen sensor or vacuum leak.